# Printout many Matlab Code files at once

Tags: matlab, code-documentation

I have a folder with many .m files (about 150) and I need to print them out on paper. I do not want to perform this manually, as this is very tedious. Is there any way to make Matlab to the work?

Comment: yes there is a way, what did you try>? ..... ...... .

Comment: and which OS do you have?

Comment: Hint: There is a command `dir` that returns all the files in the folder...

Comment: ok, I am on Windows, so you suggest working from the command line? I would still need to type in all 150 file names manually (I thought there may be a Matlab command or a selection of the 150 filenames from the MatLab GUI).
I need a printout of all of the source codes, not just the names of the files.

Comment: no, but according to this I'll write my answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Windows environment you can use :

```
txtfiles = dir('*.abc')
for n=1:numel(txtfiles);
    system(['NOTEPAD /P ' txtfiles(n).name]);
pause(2); % just pause 2 seconds and reflect on life
end
```

for all files that end with `.abc` for example.

Here we use `dir` to get the file names of the folder you are at, and matlab's `system` to actuate the command line and  then `Notepad` with its `/P` switch to print whatever `.abc` file is, even if `.abc` files aren't associated with Notepad at all (that's why I wrote `.abc`and not `.txt`, or just `.m` which you want to change to I guess).

Notepad will send its output to Windows' default printer.

Comment: thank you, this was helpful and saved me a lot of time today. Good to know it is so easy to make Matlab speak "command line" commands.
What I did not find out is how I can make notepad print in landscape format within this command line command. But I guess this is appropriate for another section here.

Comment: the best thanks is to upvote and\or "accept" the answer. Furthermore, I think that it's enough to change the default printing to landscape in your windows machine to solve it.